# display only active div onlick with jquery on wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

My problem is the following:

I want to create an image displayer.
I am using a WordPress loop to generate div:

```
 if (have_posts()) :
 $c = 0; 
 while (  have_posts() )  : the_post(); 
 $c++;
 if ( $c == 1) {
     $style = "displayfirst";
 }

 else $style ='hiddenfollowing';
```

with `.hiddenfollowing {display:none;}` in css

I wanted to add an onlick var so the next div with hiddenfollowing class appears instead of the first display div that has .displayfirst class. And of course making disappear the previously active div knowing that there is an unlimited amount of post.

Thank you.

Comment: Where's your relevant html and jQuery?

Comment: have no jquery. i tried some things but i was not working. the actual site is on blog.dansayag.com

Comment: use jquery :next http://api.jquery.com/next/